# How can Haskell read S-expressions from files?

Tags: haskell

There are some source files, which are in S-expressions. Can Haskell read those s-expressions? I need those s-expressions as patterns matched to execute the Haskell programs (suppose those s-expressions are already in the format of my haskell program data types) . For example, 
The S-expression in the file is: `ArithBiOp Plus (AInt 5) (AInt 5)`, then in the haskell program, I can match this line as `ArithBiop opcode oprand1 operand2`.

Comment: ahh, I just edited my title of the question into "How can .....". So how? like using regular Haskell read?

Comment: Haha, sorry, that's just a running joke of some sort. See my *actual* answer below.

Comment: @camccann Yes, Haskell can! Constants we can believe in! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are lucky you might be able to craft a data type that has exactly the right form to use `read` to get you data from file.  For you example:

```
data Exp = ArithBiOp Op Exp Exp | AInt Integer deriving (Show, Read)
data Op = Plus | Minus deriving (Show, Read)
```

Then you can just use `readFile` to get a string and convert that with `read`.

Answer (score 10):

If you're asking whether there's some built-in method for reading data from such files, then the answer is no, not really.

The standard type classes `Read` and `Show` are a sort of poor-man's serialization that do something similar, with the expectations that `read (show x)` == `x` and that the output of `show x`, evaluated as Haskell source, is also equal to `x`. However, if you have arbitrary expressions from some other source it's probably not safe to assume they'll match the format expected by `read`, even if (as in your example) they'll be very similar.

On the other hand, S-expressions are approximately the easiest thing to parse in the world, so it would probably be trivial to bang out something with Parsec or such to read your data.

If you can sufficiently constrain the input to be confident that it will match the output of `show` you'd get from the default instance for your types, though, then `read` ought to work. Note that the default `Read` instances are at least somewhat robust to things like spurious parentheses and whitespace:

```
> read " Just 1" :: Maybe Int
Just 1
> read " Just   1" :: Maybe Int
Just 1
> read " Just (1)" :: Maybe Int
Just 1
> read "(Just (1))" :: Maybe Int
Just 1
```

And so on.

---

Oh, and if you're asking about how to get the data from the files, you don't need to do anything special. Just use the same file I/O you'd use for anything else and give the strings to `read` or a parser. For simple stuff [the `System.IO` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-IO.html) should do everything you need.

In the extremely simple case of using `read` and having one value per line, read from stdin, the [readLn](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/src/System-IO.html#readLn) function is a convenient shortcut.